# Rotating text on graphic display

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, lcd, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to [modify](https://github.com/mattncsu/minigrafx/commit/d27f87b41d7cb9a2011fc37bf6bcd99380d47606#diff-3d1c45c53c8b19c74042e2d8fd5142bf) this [library](https://github.com/squix78/minigrafx/blob/master/src/MiniGrafx.cpp) to add the ability to rotate text on a graphic display.  I'm using an e-paper display but the library supports other graphic displays.  I have made it as far as rotating the text on the display but I can't work out getting the spin center correct.  From researching similar questions, I see that I need to temporarily move the origin to the point of rotation.  However, I am having trouble seeing how to do that with this code. `drawString` calls several functions until finally a function to set the pixel color (that is where I inserted the code to rotate the affected pixels).  I think I need to move the rotation further upstream.

I added `setTextRotation` which precomputes the sin/cos that is later passed to the first two lines in `setPixel` (at the bottom of the code block below).  It may be easier to see the changes in the first link above.  I tried solving (thanks Wolfram) a system of equations to compute a x and y that would cause the rotated pixels in the `setPixel` function to have the same origin as the original x and y passed to `drawString` but no joy. Plus, I feel like I am severely over complicating the issue.

I'm not a programmer by trade (and barely one by hobby).  Any advice on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Relevant portions (see links above for complete code):

```
int16_t txtRotation=0;
float sin_angle=0;
float cos_angle=1; 

void MiniGrafx::setTextRotation(int16_t r) {
  int16_t txtAngle=r;
  Serial.print ("Text Angle=");
  Serial.println (txtAngle);
  do
  {
    if (txtAngle>=360) txtAngle=txtAngle-360; 
      Serial.println (txtAngle);
  }while (txtAngle>360);
    do
  {
    if (txtAngle<=-360) txtAngle=txtAngle+360; 
      Serial.println (txtAngle);
  }while (txtAngle<-360);
  if (txtAngle<0) txtAngle=360+txtAngle;
    txtRotation=txtAngle;

  switch (txtRotation){
    case 0:
      sin_angle=0;
      cos_angle=1;
    break;
    case 45:
      sin_angle=0.707106781;
      cos_angle=0.707106781;
    break;
    case 90:
      sin_angle=1;
      cos_angle=0;
    break;
    case 135:
      sin_angle=0.707106781;
      cos_angle=-0.707106781;
    break;
    case 180:
      sin_angle=0;
      cos_angle=-1;
    break;
    case 225:
      sin_angle=-0.707106781;
      cos_angle=-0.707106781;
    break;
    case 270:
      sin_angle=-1;
      cos_angle=0;
    break;
    case 315:
      sin_angle=-0.707106781;
      cos_angle=0.707106781;
    break;
    default: //compute sin and cos if not a cardinal direction.
      float angle_rad=0.017453*(float)txtRotation; //convert degrees to radians
      sin_angle = sin (angle_rad);          // Pre-calculate the time consuming sin
      cos_angle = cos (angle_rad);          // Pre-calculate the time consuming cosine
    break;
  }

}

void MiniGrafx::drawString(int16_t xMove, int16_t yMove, String strUser) {
  uint16_t lineHeight = pgm_read_byte(fontData + HEIGHT_POS);

  // char* text must be freed!
  char* text = utf8ascii(strUser);

  uint16_t yOffset = 0;
  // If the string should be centered vertically too
  // we need to now how heigh the string is.
  if (textAlignment == TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER_BOTH) {
    uint16_t lb = 0;
    // Find number of linebreaks in text
    for (uint16_t i=0;text[i] != 0; i++) {
      lb += (text[i] == 10);
    }
    // Calculate center
    yOffset = (lb * lineHeight) >> 2;
  }

  uint16_t line = 0;
  char* textPart = strtok(text,"\n");
  while (textPart != NULL) {
    uint16_t length = strlen(textPart);
    drawStringInternal((xMove, yMove - yOffset + (line++) * lineHeight, textPart, length, getStringWidth(textPart, length));
    textPart = strtok(NULL, "\n");
  }
  free(text);
}

void MiniGrafx::drawStringInternal(int16_t xMove, int16_t yMove, char* text, uint16_t textLength, uint16_t textWidth) {
  uint8_t textHeight       = pgm_read_byte(fontData + HEIGHT_POS);
  uint8_t firstChar        = pgm_read_byte(fontData + FIRST_CHAR_POS);
  uint16_t sizeOfJumpTable = pgm_read_byte(fontData + CHAR_NUM_POS)  * JUMPTABLE_BYTES;

  uint8_t cursorX         = 0;
  uint8_t cursorY         = 0;

  switch (textAlignment) {
    case TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER_BOTH:
      yMove -= textHeight >> 1;
    // Fallthrough
    case TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER:
      xMove -= textWidth >> 1; // divide by 2
      break;
    case TEXT_ALIGN_RIGHT:
      xMove -= textWidth;
      break;
  }

  // Don't draw anything if it is not on the screen.
  if (xMove + textWidth  < 0 || xMove > this->width ) {return;}
  if (yMove + textHeight < 0 || yMove > this->height) {return;}

  for (uint16_t j = 0; j < textLength; j++) {
    int16_t xPos = xMove + cursorX;
    int16_t yPos = yMove + cursorY;

    byte code = text[j];
    if (code >= firstChar) {
      byte charCode = code - firstChar;

      // 4 Bytes per char code
      byte msbJumpToChar    = pgm_read_byte( fontData + JUMPTABLE_START + charCode * JUMPTABLE_BYTES );                  // MSB  \ JumpAddress
      byte lsbJumpToChar    = pgm_read_byte( fontData + JUMPTABLE_START + charCode * JUMPTABLE_BYTES + JUMPTABLE_LSB);   // LSB /
      byte charByteSize     = pgm_read_byte( fontData + JUMPTABLE_START + charCode * JUMPTABLE_BYTES + JUMPTABLE_SIZE);  // Size
      byte currentCharWidth = pgm_read_byte( fontData + JUMPTABLE_START + charCode * JUMPTABLE_BYTES + JUMPTABLE_WIDTH); // Width

      // Test if the char is drawable
      if (!(msbJumpToChar == 255 && lsbJumpToChar == 255)) {
        // Get the position of the char data
        uint16_t charDataPosition = JUMPTABLE_START + sizeOfJumpTable + ((msbJumpToChar << 8) + lsbJumpToChar);
        drawInternal(xPos, yPos, currentCharWidth, textHeight, fontData, charDataPosition, charByteSize);
      }

      cursorX += currentCharWidth;
    }
  }
}

void MiniGrafx::setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGNMENT textAlignment) {
  this->textAlignment = textAlignment;
}

uint16_t MiniGrafx::getStringWidth(const char* text, uint16_t length) {
  uint16_t firstChar        = pgm_read_byte(fontData + FIRST_CHAR_POS);

  uint16_t stringWidth = 0;
  uint16_t maxWidth = 0;

  while (length--) {
    stringWidth += pgm_read_byte(fontData + JUMPTABLE_START + (text[length] - firstChar) * JUMPTABLE_BYTES + JUMPTABLE_WIDTH);
    if (text[length] == 10) {
      maxWidth = max(maxWidth, stringWidth);
      stringWidth = 0;
    }
  }
  return max(maxWidth, stringWidth);
}

void inline MiniGrafx::drawInternal(int16_t xMove, int16_t yMove, int16_t width, int16_t height, const char *data, uint16_t offset, uint16_t bytesInData) {
  if (width < 0 || height < 0) return;
  if (yMove + height < 0 || yMove > this->height)  return;
  if (xMove + width  < 0 || xMove > this->width)   return;

  uint8_t  rasterHeight = 1 + ((height - 1) >> 3); // fast ceil(height / 8.0)
  int8_t   yOffset      = yMove & 7;

  bytesInData = bytesInData == 0 ? width * rasterHeight : bytesInData;

  int16_t initYMove   = yMove;
  int8_t  initYOffset = yOffset;

  uint8_t arrayHeight = (int) ceil(height / 8.0);
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < bytesInData; i++) {
    byte currentByte = pgm_read_byte(data + offset + i);

    for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++) {
      if(bitRead(currentByte, b)) {
        uint16_t currentBit = i * 8 + b;
        uint16_t pixelX = (i / arrayHeight);
        uint16_t pixelY = (i % arrayHeight) * 8;
        setPixel(pixelX + xMove, pixelY + yMove + b);
      }
    }
    yield();

  }
}

void MiniGrafx::setPixel(uint16_t x, uint16_t y) {

  uint16_t newX = (int) (((float)x * cos_angle) - ((float)y * sin_angle));
  uint16_t newY = (int) (((float)y * cos_angle) + ((float)x * sin_angle));

  if (newX >= width || newY >= height || newX < 0 || newY < 0 || color < 0 || color > 15 || color == transparentColor) return;
  uint16_t pos = (newY * width + newX) >> bitShift;
  if (pos > bufferSize) {
    return;
  }
  uint8_t shift = (newX & (pixelsPerByte - 1)) * bitsPerPixel;
  uint8_t mask = bitMask << shift;
  uint8_t palColor = color;
  palColor = palColor << shift;
  buffer[pos] = (buffer[pos] & ~mask) | (palColor & mask);
}
```